# Matplotlib table plot, how to add gap between the graph and table

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

**How to add gap between the graph and table when plotting table in Matplotlib?**

This is [my code](https://gist.github.com/suntong/c12e195983ecf6d5a4d4/9ffbe2865705f35113634cf4a2e884de9b618770):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dc = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1, 2, 3, 4],'B' : [4, 3, 2, 1],'C' : [3, 4, 2, 2]})

plt.plot(dc)
plt.legend(dc.columns)
dcsummary = pd.DataFrame([dc.mean(), dc.sum()],index=['Mean','Total'])

plt.table(cellText=dcsummary.values,colWidths = [0.25]*len(dc.columns),
        rowLabels=dcsummary.index,
        colLabels=dcsummary.columns,
        cellLoc = 'center', rowLoc = 'center',
        loc='bottom')
# loc='top'
fig = plt.gcf()

plt.show()
```

and the result looks like this:

[image: plt.table]

I.e., the table header is in the way of x-labels.
How to add gap between the graph and table? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `bbox` argument:

```
plt.table(cellText=dcsummary.values,colWidths = [0.25]*len(dc.columns),
rowLabels=dcsummary.index,
colLabels=dcsummary.columns,
cellLoc = 'center', rowLoc = 'center',
loc='bottom', bbox=[0.25, -0.5, 0.5, 0.3])
```

Comment: for example you can use this position: `bbox=[0.1, -0.3, 0.9, 0.2]`

Comment: Excellent! Please give a reference where I can find `bbox` document as well (or explain what they are and why they work that way). thanks

Comment: @xpt There's a lot of information about it [http://matplotlib.org/](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html?highlight=bbox#matplotlib.text.Text.set_bbox)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm still at lost view them though. So what exactly are the 0.1, -0.3, 0.9, 0.2 four values are for? Why you choose these values (i.e., why they are better than 0.25, -0.5, 0.5, 0.3)? Which one control the gap between the graph and table? Thx.

Comment: The first coordinate is a shift on the x-axis, second coordinate is a gap between plot and text box (table in your case), third coordinate is a width of the text box, fourth coordinate is a height of text box.